# Excel formula to dynamically create a sum range is erroring "a value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying write a formula in one cell that uses 2 other cells as the beginning and end of a range of cells from another sheet then offset 1 column and sum the values. I keep getting the error "a value used in the formula is of the wrong data type". When I step through the formulas everything seems to be correct until it gets to the final Sum() then it errors with #Value.

One attempt (this one does not have the offset one column as I never got that far before it errored):

```
=SUM(CELL("address",INDEX('F Mod'!AQ6:AQ15,MATCH('NC Sign'!E123,'F Mod'!AQ6:AQ15,0)))&":"&CELL("address",INDEX('F Mod'!AQ6:AQ15,MATCH('NC Sign'!E124,'F Mod'!AQ6:AQ15,0))))
```

Evaluates down to:

```
=SUM("'[CSLT Information Flow Master (version 2).xlsm]F Mod'!$AQ$6"&":"&"'[CSLT Information Flow Master (version 2).xlsm]F Mod'!$AQ$8")
```

Then errors.

Another attempt (has offset by altering the column in the address function):

```
=SUM(ADDRESS(MATCH(E123,'F Mod'!$AQ:$AQ,0),44)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(E124,'F Mod'!$AQ:$AQ,0),44))
```

Evaluates down to:

```
=SUM("$AR$6:$AR$8")
```

then errors.

It has to be something I am missing when it comes to the Sum() function but I am lost.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you could show us some sample data.

Comment: You created a string that needs to be nested in`INDIRECT()` >> `=SUM(INDIRECT("$AR$6:$AR$8"))`, however I do agree with @Ike. Just add a smaller set of sample data that would capture what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I've add a screenshot to give a better picture of what my issue is.

Comment: @Hareborn avoid using volatile functions, try with `INDEX()` function it gives you the same output which makes the excel works faster and better, also it neiether slows down nor recalculates Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Formula in B13 is:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT("G"&2+MATCH(B6;$F$3:$F$20;0));0;0;MATCH(B7;$F$3:$F$20;0)-MATCH(B6;$F$3:$F$20;0)+1;1))
```

Notice the INDIRECT part, where I typed `INDIRECT("G"&2+MATCH` That `2` comes from one row above data starts. Because data starts at row 3, then I typed 2.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to adapt this code to my needs the easiest. I now have 34 adaptation of it working across 3 sheets and 47 ranges. As a side question can anyone explain to me why when using cell("address") function, as I tried and miserably failed earlier, it returns the complete address to include the workbook name?

Comment: @Hareborn Cell("adresss") returns a string, that's all. You need INDIRECT to return a range of cells.

Answer (score 2):

You may ***try*** in this way as well,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **D4**

```
=SUM(INDEX($H$2:$H$17,MATCH($B$5,$G$2:$G$17,0)):
INDEX($H$2:$H$17,MATCH($B$8,$G$2:$G$17,0)))
```

---

**Note:** Use `INDEX()` Function to return a reference and not a value, the use of full lookup then the colon, then another full lookup gives Excel the hint it needs that it must return a reference.

Therefore it makes a range of the two cells located and passes that to the `SUM()` Function wrapping around everything else.

---

Also, note if you are using **O365**, then you can use `XLOOKUP()` Function as well,

[image: DYNAMIC_FORMULA_RANGE]

• Formula used in cell **D10**

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP($B$11,$G$2:$G$17,$H$2:$H$17):
XLOOKUP($B$14,$G$2:$G$17,$H$2:$H$17))
```

Answer (score 0):

1] Using Sum+Offset function

In `D2`, enter formula :

```
=SUM(OFFSET(H1,MATCH(B5,G:G,0)-1,,RIGHT(B8,4)-RIGHT(B5,4)+1))
```

Or,

2] Using Sum+Indirect function

In `D2`, enter formula :

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("H"&MATCH(B5,G:G,0)&":H"&MATCH(B8,G:G,0)))
```

[image]