# SUMIFS with dynamic range of sum columns based on start and end month input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On Sheet1, I have a table of data with headers in D1:O1 of Jan-23, Feb-23,...Dec-23. There are several hundred rows of data below each month.

On Sheet2, in cells B1 and B2 I enter start and end months defining a range of months (e.g., B1 = Jan-23, B2 = Aug-23)

I would like to write a SUMIFS that will take the months given in B1 and B2 and use those to define the sum range, using the whole column to sum all data for the given range of months meeting the criteria I will give in the formula. I have tried the following to define the dynamic sum range:

`=SUMIFS(INDEX(Input!$D$3:$O$293,0,MATCH($B$1,Input!$D$1:$O$1,0)):INDEX(Input!$D$3:$O$293,0,MATCH($B$2,Input!$D$1:$O$1,0)),...)`

This is throwing an error. Can someone please suggest how I can use Sheet2!B1 and Sheet2!B2 to define a sum range for this SUMIFS formula?

Comment: Do you have M365? What does *"meeting the criteria I will give in the formula"* look like?

Comment: It should not throw an error, may be you are not using `MS365` hence which needs to be entered using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` can you post some sample data. Well edit, since you are using a `union` `:` it will not work with `SUMIFS()` it should be `SUM()` instead. That said the formula will be `=SUM(INDEX(Input!$D$3:$O$293,0,MATCH($B$1,Input!$D$1:$O$1,0)):INDEX(Input!$D$3:$O$293,0,MATCH($B$2,Input!$D$1:$O$1,0)))`

Comment: Refer this post, I have posted two solution approaches using `INDEX()`+`MATCH()` as well as using `XLOOKUP()` **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71795105/8162520)**

Comment: I need to use SUMIFS because I have other multiple criteria I need to match in Sheet1!A:C.

Comment: Can you post some sample data using **[Mardown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** showing your input and output

Comment: An appropriate solution will depend on the values in your header row... are they text (ie: "Jan-23") or are they dates formatted as "mmm-yy" (ie: 01/31/23)? `SUMPRODUCT()` would be ideal if your headers are dates. Another option would be to use a helper column on your Input sheet to perform a `SUMIFS()` for each row in your data table, based on the column header criteria; then, use the helper column as the *sum_range* for all of your `SUMIFS()` functions on Sheet2, based on whatever row criteria you're using.